# Twilio: Retrieving Lat and Long from incoming Android Location

Tags: android, google-maps, twilio

I am trying to figure out how to program in Twilio when receiving a sent current location from android phones. We have a product that asks you to attach your current location. I have noticed that almost every android phone sends in different data. If it was always sending the lat and long in the message like this example:

13346-13400 Detroit Road Detroit, MI 48999 USA http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=(41.3802144,-82.4114423)

I would be able to grab the lat and long and display it for the company using our product.

But I also receive info like this which doesn't have lat and long in the message:

5112 Maryland Rd
https://maps.google.com/maps?ftid=0x89b7dff4ce9e32d5:0xb0a7528b4b4f1268
5112 Maryland Rd, Baltomore, MD 21114, USA"

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can take the address and automatically grab the lat and long or by asking twilio to grab the link and populate the lat and long?

I am new to this so I apologize is my message isn't clear. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you need is a geocoding API. Geocoding is the process of taking an address and turning it into latitude and longitude.

I recommend you take a look through [Google's documentation and Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and see what you can achieve with that. There are other APIs out there, but this would be a good start for you.